# How to copy a file to application folder in set up project during insatllation. File is in set up folder

Tags: c#, setup-project

I have a xml file in the setup folder of a windows application. Now during the installation how do i copy this file to my application's folder so that it can be copied to this path C:\Program Files (x86).......

I can not add the file to the application folder in the setup project because the content of file might change after build of setup project.

Its an external xml file in located inside set up folder. and I want to copy this file on installation path(C:/Program Files...) during installation. I will give this file with msi installer in side installer folder.

Please provide any idea if someone have....

Comment: A C# file? Your own application?

Comment: No, its an external xml file in located inside set up folder. and I want to copy this file on installation path(C:/Program Files...) during installation. I will give this file with msi installer in side installer folder.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly, this might solve your problem, or at least get you started:

Include the file in the main project (for instance in a folder called "resources"). Right click the file in VS, choose `properties`, and set `Copy to output directory` to `Coppy Always`.